# Добавление в избранное

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, php7

Как сделать чтобы при нажатии на span отправлялась форма?

```
<form action="" method="POST">      
    <input type="hidden" name="id_user" value="<? echo "$id"; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="id_room" value="<? echo "$id_room"; ?>" />   
    <span  class="like-icon with-tip" data-tip-content="Добавить в избранное" ></span>
</form>
```

Comment: Ни один из тегов вопроса сюда не клеится. Из этого делаю вывод, что вам, чем проще решение, тем лучше. Допишите следующий атрибут в кнопку: `onclick="this.parentNode.submit();"`. Но мне не понятно, почему нельзя сделать кнопку именно кнопкой, т.е. элементом `<button type="submit">`?

Comment: @Deonis тогда кнопка будет просто активировать звезду и не будет отправлять данные

Comment: @user402416 С чего это? `type="submit"`, и кнопка будет отправлять данные.

Comment: @Deonis если использовать onclick="this.parentNode.submit();" то так получиться отправить? if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $id_user=$_POST['id_user'];
  $id_room=$_POST['id_room'];
    
  $sql="INSERT INTO bookmarked (id_user,id_room) values ('$id_user','$id_room')";
  $run_query=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
 }

Answer (score 0):

Измени HTML на:

```
<form action="" method="POST">      
    <input type="hidden" name="id_user" value="<? echo "$id"; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="id_room" value="<? echo "$id_room"; ?>" />   
    <span  class="like-icon with-tip" data-tip-content="Добавить в избранное" onclick="this.parentElement.submit();"></span>
</form>
```

А с помощью php проверять оправлина ли форма будеш так:

```
if(isset($_POST['id_user']) && isset($_POST['id_room'])) {
    // code . . .
}
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: this.parentNode.submit is not a function кнопок с именем submit нет

Comment: @user402416 просто измени parentNode на parentElement